# Rails: logger.debug not working inside Model function

Tags: ruby-on-rails, debugging, logging

I have a bunch of `logger.debug` statements in my `Controller`. They currently write the place where all the `HTTP` requests and everything are displayed in real time on my WEBRick server. However, 
when I write `logger.debug` statements in my Model, they are not written to this same location, additionally they are not to be found in `log/development` which is the environment I have been working in. It is particularly frustrating because I make the call to the following Model function in a controller that has successfully executed `logger.debug` statements:

```
  def process_payment
   uri = URI('https://demo.myvirtualmerchant.com/VirtualMerchant/processxml.do')

   the_xml = SchoolApplication.to_xml(params[:credit_card], 
                                 params[:expiration],
                                 params[:cvv2_cvc2],
                                 params[:amount],
                                 params[:name])
   logger.debug(the_xml)
   the_xml = the_xml.to_s
   my_hash = {'xmldata' => the_xml} 
   logger.debug(the_xml)
   response = Net::HTTP.post_form(uri, my_hash)

   @response_var = response
    if response.response == 0 
      render 'receipt'
    else
      render 'card_Error'
    end
  end
```

the two `logger.debug` statements in this controller method are written to what I suppose is STDOUT? In any case I *see* them in the location which displays the following kind of information:

```
  Rendered web_applications/card_Error.html.erb within layouts/application (1.7ms)
Completed 200 OK in 433ms (Views: 13.1ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)


Started GET "/assets/jquery.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-07-22 11:32:02 -0700
```

In the above Controller method when I make the call to `SchoolApplication.to_xml`,
it does *not* execute the corresponding logger.debug() statements (or maybe it writes them
to a different place? That wouldn't make sense but I am also a n00b, clearly) that are in 
`to_xml` `Model` method as shown below:

```
   def self.to_xml(number,expiration,cvv,amount, name)
     xml = ::Builder::XmlMarkup.new
     logger.debug(number)
     logger.debug(name)
     xml.txn {

       xml.ssl_test_mode false  
       xml.ssl_card_number number
       xml.ssl_amount amount
       xml.ssl_cvv2cvc2_indicator cvv
       xml.ssl_first_name name
       xml.ssl_show_form false
       xml.ssl_exp_date '25/34'
       xml.ssl_track_data 
       xml.ssl_result_format HTML
       xml.ssl_receipt_link_method 
       xml.ssl_receipt_link_url "#{Rails.root}" + '/receipts/receive'
       xml.ssl_receipt_link_text
     }
     xml 
   end
```

N.B. I know that the above `to_xml` is being successfully called and returned from as the rest of my controller method which calls this model function executes without error.

Here is the output after I go to the route which calls the `process_payment` controller function:

```
Started POST "/application/pay" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-07-22 12:13:40 -0700
Processing by WebApplicationsController#process_payment as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"pJD6Q7qJPXFNaGEczv5kTSKBC5TcG8lqhOuLNjw9UrY=",  "web_application"=>{"first_name"=>"bob", "last_name"=>"job", "card_number"=>"41111111111111", "expiration_date"=>"232", "cvv2_cvc2"=>"232"}, "commit"=>"Save Web application"}
<txn><ssl_merchant_id/><ssl_user_id/><ssl_ssl_pin/><ssl_test_mode>false</ssl_test_mode>    <ssl_card_number/><ssl_amount/><ssl_cvv2cvc2_indicator/><ssl_first_name/ ><ssl_show_form>false</ssl_show_form><ssl_exp_date>25/34</ssl_exp_date><ssl_track_data/><ssl_result_format>HTML</ssl_result_format><ssl_receipt_link_method/><ssl_receipt_link_url>  <ssl_receipt_link_text/></txn><to_s/>
<txn><ssl_merchant_id/><ssl_user_id/><ssl_ssl_pin/><ssl_test_mode>false</ssl_test_mode>    <ssl_card_number/><ssl_amount/><ssl_cvv2cvc2_indicator/><ssl_first_name/><ssl_show_form>false</ssl_show_form><ssl_exp_date>25/34</ssl_exp_date><ssl_track_data/><ssl_result_format>HTML</ssl_result_format><ssl_receipt_link_method/>
 Rendered web_applications/card_Error.html.erb within layouts/application (3.8ms)
Completed 200 OK in 742ms (Views: 22.6ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

which is equivalent to what was written in `development.log`

Comment: Which Ruby and Rails versions are you using?

Comment: 4.0.4 (Via `rails -v`)

Comment: And you don't have `log_level` set in `development.rb`  or `application.rb`?

Comment: Just put in one of my methods `  def self.search(params, user = nil)
    logger.debug "search search search";` and it totally works. Using Rails 4.0.8.

Comment: put that verbatim in my Model file?

Comment: I don't have `log_level` set.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57790/discussion-between-thalatta-and-michal-szyndel).